# JavaScript .active doesn't seem to be working for me

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

So, on my website's home page I have a list of services. The idea is that when you click on one of them, a description appears alongside it relating to that service. However, clicking on said buttons doesn't do anything and I'm not entirely sure why. This JS function is the same as what I'm using for my menu button, which performs perfectly.

I'm no professional with code and would still describe myself as a beginner so any help on the matter is very much appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.video-btn').click(function() {
    $('description-video').toggleClass('active');
  })
  $('.animation-btn').click(function() {
    $('description-animation').toggleClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
.description {
  width: 600px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-left: 4px solid #e0bd8c;
}

#description-video,
#description-animation {
  display: none;
}

#description-video.active,
#description-animation.active {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="service-list">
  <li id="video-btn"><a href="#">Video</a></li>
  <li id="animation-btn"><a href="#">Animation</a></li>
</ul>

<p class="description" id="description-video">
  Text goes here...
</p>

<p class="description" id="description-animation">
  Text goes here...
</p>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: are there any errors you are getting?

Comment: `.video-btn` is a class. You have IDs

Comment: You have links but your event handler is on the LI

Comment: Only 2 for a missing temp png for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things :

In clicks identifiers they are classes, but you defined it as ids in your html

```
  $('#video-btn').click(function() {
  $('#animation-btn').click(function() {
```

Your forgot the prefix on toggleClass identifiers

```
$('#description-video').toggleClass('active');
$('#description-animation').toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! I figured it would be a simple fix. Thanks for the help mate!

Comment: More than two things :) See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64682055/295783) for a more scalable solution

Answer (score 0):

- .video-btn is a class. You have IDs
- You have links but your event handler is on the LI
- missing # on the selector

You need to delegate and use data-attributes

```js
$(function() {
  $('.service-list').on("click",'.btn a', function() {
    $("#"+this.dataset.desc).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.description {
  width: 600px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-left: 4px solid #e0bd8c;
}

#description-video,
#description-animation {
  display: none;
}

#description-video.active,
#description-animation.active {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="service-list">
  <li class="btn"><a href="#" data-desc="description-video">Video</a></li>
  <li class="btn"><a href="#" data-desc="description-animation">Animation</a></li>
</ul>

<p class="description" id="description-video">
  Text goes here...
</p>

<p class="description" id="description-animation">
  Text goes here...
</p>
```